# Removing a newline from the middle of a row of data

Tags: awk, sed, newline

I have tried the following which have not worked.  The file has no field delimiters.  It is fixed width.
I do not care if I use awk or sed.  The newline appears to be in column 50.  I have also tried column 49.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
awk '{ gsub(/\n,"", $50); print } ' newsqtp160 > UPD_newsqtp16  
awk '{ gsub(\n,"", $50); print } ' newsqtp160 > UPD_newsqtp16
awk '{gsub(/\\n/, "", $49); print}' newsqtp160 > UPD_newsqtp16
sed 's/\n//50' newsqtp160 > UPD_newsqtp16
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, thanks for sharing your attempted codes here, could you please do mention sample of input and expected output in your question and let us know then.

Comment: What do you mean with : `The file has no field delimiters. It is fixed width.` . Could you provide some sample of input and the expected output ?

Answer (score 1):

You can think about this problem in another perspective instead of replacing the new line using `gsub` or sed's `s/.../`.

You have already told us that your file has fixed width lines, if there is a broken line, it's length should be shorter than the "fixed" width, no matter the linebreak sits in 50th or 49th column. So you can just do:

```
awk -v n="FIXED_LENGTH" '{s=s $0}length(s)==n{print s;s=""}' file
```

Basically, the above line does:

If a line has length == fixed width, print it out, otherwise, join with next line, and next line, and next... till it reaches the fixed width.

#### Test

Let's see a small test:

Here the fixed_width is "4".

```
kent$  cat f
1234
1234
12
34
1234
1
2
3
4
1234

kent$  awk -v n="4" '{s=s $0}length(s)==n{print s;s=""}' f
1234
1234
1234
1234
1234
1234
```